# Identify Type of Recursive Sequence?

Tags: recursive-algorithms, trees

I would love to learn techniques for solving the following, but I can't seem to identify this type of sequence: let $N > 0$ and let $k$ be an arbitrary positive integer between $0$ and $N-1$ (inclusive) and consider the sequence:

$$\lambda_k = \frac1{N-k} - \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{k-j} \lambda_j\;.$$

$\lambda_0 \equiv 1/N$. This generates sequences like:

$$\frac1N,\frac1{N-1}-\frac1N = \frac1{N(N-1)},\frac1{N-2} - 2\left(\frac1{N-1} - \frac1N\right) - \frac1N =\frac2{N(N-1)(N-2)},\dots$$

it *seems* that $\lambda_k$ is always equal to an integer divided by $N(N-1)(N-2)\dots(N-k)$ (believe me, I understand how dangerous the word *seems* can be). In fact, I wrote a small recursive C program to test the sums (for small $C,k$ otherwise it takes forever) and it also *seems* that $\lambda_{N-1} = 1/N$, but I can't see how to prove that in general.

Any replies pointing me to references about these types of sequences (if they exist) would be appreciated.

Comment: $\binom{n}k$ is `\binom{n}{k}`. Did you mean to subtract the sum from $\frac1{N-k}$?

Comment: Oh, s**t, yes, I did. And I had checked it so CAREFULLY. :) I've made the change now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that

$$\lambda_k=\frac{k!}{N^\underline{k+1}}\;,$$

where $x^{\underline k}=x(x-1)\dots(x-k+1)$ is the [falling factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol). This can be proved by induction on $k$. Assuming that it’s true below $k$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\lambda_k&=\frac1{N-k}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{k-j}\frac{j!}{N^{\underline{j+1}}}\\\\
&=\frac1{N-k}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{k!}{(k-j)!N^{\underline{j+1}}}\\\\
&=\frac1{N-k}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{k^{\underline j}}{N^{\underline{j+1}}}\\\\
&=\frac{N^{\underline k}}{N^{\underline{k+1}}}-\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{k^{\underline{j-1}}}{N^{\underline j}}\\\\
&=\frac{N^{\underline k}}{N^{\underline{k+1}}}-\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{k^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}}{N^{\underline{k+1}}}\\\\
&=\frac1{N^{\underline{k+1}}}\left(N^{\underline k}-\sum_{j=1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so we want to show that

$$N^{\underline k}-\sum_{j=1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}=k!\;.$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}
N^{\underline k}-\sum_{j=1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}&=N^{\underline k}-(N-1)^{\underline k}-\sum_{j=2}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\\\\
&=\Big(N-(N-k)\Big)(N-1)^{\underline{k-1}}-\sum_{j=2}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\\\\
&=k(N-1)^{\underline{k-1}}-\sum_{j=2}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\\\\
&=k(N-1)^{\underline{k-1}}-k(N-2)^{\underline{k-1}}-\sum_{j=3}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\\\\
&=k\Big((N-1)-(N-k)\Big)(N-2)^{\underline{k-2}}-\sum_{j=3}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\\\\
&=k^{\underline 2}(N-2)^{\underline{k-2}}-\sum_{j=3}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\\\\
&\;\vdots\\\\
&=k^{\underline\ell}(N-\ell)^{\underline{k-\ell}}-\sum_{j=\ell+1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\\\\
&\;\vdots\\\\
&=k^{\underline{k-1}}(N-k+1)-k^{\underline{k-1}}(N-k)\\\\
&=k^{\underline{k-1}}\\\\
&=k!\;.
\end{align*}$$

**Added:** I had some time and recast this computation as a proper proof by induction.

**Claim:** For $\ell=0,\dots,k-1$,

$$N^{\underline k}-\sum_{j=1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}=k^{\underline\ell}(N-\ell)^{\underline{k-\ell}}-\sum_{j=\ell+1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\;.\tag{1}$$

**Proof.** For $\ell=0$ there is nothing to prove: the righthand side of $(1)$ **is** the lefthand side. Now assume that $(1)$ holds for some $\ell<k-1$. For typographical convenience let $$S(\ell)=\sum_{j=\ell+1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}\;.$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
N^{\underline k}-\sum_{j=1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}&=k^{\underline\ell}(N-\ell)^{\underline{k-\ell}}-S(\ell)\\\\
&=k^{\underline\ell}(N-\ell)^{\underline{k-\ell}}-k^{\underline\ell}\big(N-(\ell+1)\big)^{k-\ell}-S(\ell+1)\\\\
&=k^{\underline\ell}\Big((N-\ell)-(N-k)\Big)\big(N-(\ell+1)\big)^{\underline{k-(\ell+1)}}-S(\ell+1)\\\\
&=k^{\underline\ell}(k-\ell)\big(N-(\ell+1)\big)^{\underline{k-(\ell+1)}}-S(\ell+1)\\\\
&=k^{\underline{\ell+1}}\big(N-(\ell+1)\big)^{\underline{k-(\ell+1)}}-S(\ell+1)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the induction goes through. $\dashv$

In particular, taking $\ell=k-1$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
N^{\underline k}-\sum_{j=1}^kk^{\underline{j-1}}(N-j)^{\underline{k+1-j}}&=k^{\underline{k-1}}(N-k+1)-k^{\underline{k-1}}(N-k)\\
&=k^{\underline{k-1}}\\
&=k!\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Brian, many thanks, I've just seen your answer so I haven't digested it yet. I'm sure it's correct (and thanks for pointing out that sign error) and I'm going to investigate a proof by induction, although I had tried that many times before, in different ways. Funny thing is I was starting to investigate Ganot numbers because it seems, in one way or another, that if I change notation to include $N$, say $\lambda(N,k)$, that $\lambda(N,k) = -1 \lambda(N,k-1) + \lambda(N-1,k-1)$. How I would have ever found "falling factorial" I don't know, but hopefully this is the end of my journey.

Comment: @Norman: You’re welcome; it was an interesting problem. I’ve added the subsidiary proof by induction that I originally left as a long computation; the main induction was in the original answer.